# Best practice when mounting a new disk within an existing mount?

Tags: mount, filesystem, disk

I have a 6 year old media PC, which also happens to be the home fileserver.  It has a 2TB hard drive mounted under /home

Under /home there are 9 different main folders, but one of them (the mythtv recordings and videos) is taking up roughly half of the capacity and running me out of space.

I want to increase my disk capacity, but not sure whether to replace the disk with a 4tb one, or add a second 2tb disk to the filesystem at /home/mythtv and migrating the existing data there.  Bearing in mind that /home is already a mount point in fstab, would this be bad practice?

Essentially the question is - *should you mount within a mount point* and, if not, what better options are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, every mountpoint except `/` is within another mountpoint. Your `/home`, for example, is a mountpoint in another mountpoint. There's nothing special about that whatsoever. This is safe, common and standard. So just create your mountpoint and add the new filesystem there.

First, move the current contents of `/home/mythtv` somewhere else, then mount the new drive to the now empty `/home/mythtv` directory and then move the data over.

Comment: I was curious whether the order of the `mount` command matters in this case and asked a [follow-up question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1106879/504066).

Comment: @PerlDuck it does. Things are mounted sequentially.