# Does order of mount operations matter when mounting into an existing mountpoint?

Tags: mount

The question [Best practice when mounting a new disk within an existing mount?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1106867/504066)
inspired me to ask this follow-up question:

The other question asked whether it is ok to

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /home
mount /dev/sdb2 /home/mythtv
```

so that `/home/mythtv` is a mountpoint within the mountpoint 
`/home`. (*spoiler*: Yes, it is perfectly ok.).

What if I'd change the order of commands to

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /home/mythtv
mount /dev/sdb1 /home
```

Will that yield the same result or will `/home/mythtv` be *hidden* by `/home`?
I assume `/home` contains an (empty) directory `/home/mythtv`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it matters! Your first example:

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /home
mount /dev/sdb2 /home/mythtv
```

is the only right way, when mounting you must respect the tree order.

In your second example,

```
mount /dev/sdb2 /home/mythtv
mount /dev/sdb1 /home
```

If we are assuming `/home/mythtv` exists on the filesystem, it is gonna mount it with no problem, but after you mount the second volume you won't be able to access the first one anymore.

This is because you let the system mount `sdb2` on an existing path at `/home/mythtv`. When you mount on `/home/`, you are telling your system to mount it on the `/home` path which also exists but is going to "cover" existing mount point. They are both mounted, but when you type `cd /home/mythtv`, Bash takes you to `sdb1:/home/mythtv` instead `sdb2:/home/mythtv` because they are different paths.

I hope the explanation is clear. If not, please ask in the comments, I'll try to get it to you more clearly.

**Update**

as per @mook765's comment, the order is important also in the `fstab` files:

The `fstab` file is read up to down while mounting, and down to up when umounting. In another case, if you try to umount `/home` before `/home/mythtv` mount will tell you the `/home` resource is busy because you have the `/home/mythtv` mounted and it cannot handle it.

Comment: @PerlDuck This is also important for `/etc/fstab`, line order matters.

Comment: Yes Absolutely, @mook765 say the true, fstab file when mount is read up to down, and when umount down to up, in other case if you try to umount /home before /home/mythtv mount will say to you the /home resource is busy, because have the /home/mythtv mounted and cannot handle it.

Comment: In which cases would `/etc/fstab` be used for unmounting? The only thing I could think of is `umount -a`, but that command looks at what's actually mounted, not `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: by reading here seems it also used by umount: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html, anyway after thinking a while on this (if you can confirm to me) the umount go to read the fstab when you invoke: umount /mount/point. But I repeat, may I misunderstanding the process of umount, the mount I'm sure is gonna to work like I had describe.

Comment: Up to down? You mean bottom up or top down???