# Does the order in which devices are listed in fstab matter?

Tags: mount, fstab

All the information I find about the fstab file shows that the units are listed chronologically.

```
sda1
sda2
sdb1
etc...
```

My fstab file is listed as follows:

```
sda2 (root)
sda1 (efi)
sda3 (swap)
```

Computer works, but starts a little slow, it takes a long time to connect `sda2`.

Therefore, I wonder how the devices are listed in the fstab file
has some significance

Comment: You probably mean alphabetically rather than chronologically… If your root partition is slow to mount, there might be a problem with the filesystem but you provided too little information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does order of mount operations matter when mounting into an existing mountpoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106879/does-order-of-mount-operations-matter-when-mounting-into-an-existing-mountpoint)

Answer (score 2):

From [`man fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man5/fstab.5.html) (Lubuntu 19.04):

> ```
> fstab - static information about the filesystems
>
> The  file  fstab  contains  descriptive  information  about the filesystems the system can
> mount.  fstab is only read by programs, and not written; it is  the  duty  of  the  system
> administrator to properly create and maintain this file.  The order of records in fstab is
> important because fsck(8), mount(8), and  umount(8)  sequentially  iterate  through  fstab
> doing their thing.
> ```

If you had a separate `/home` (or other directory) partition, it'd be mounted on-top of `/`, so of course `/` should be listed first.  This can be taken advantage of, though usually not with default `fstab` mounts.